# IIS 7.5 routing not working (all usual methods tested)

Tags: asp.net, routes, iis-7.5

I have a client who has one webpage with customized routes added in global.asax (they are extension-less):

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Clear()
Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Key1", "String", "~/Route")
```

Unfortunately this redirections are not working on IIS 7.5. I've tested that:

- HTTP redirection is installed over IIS
- Tried to runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" (in the web.config)
- Use the manual add of UrlRoutingMode (http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html)

The pool in in integrated mode, 4.0. This server is running a lot of MVC3 pages, and they are using routing by default.

Any light will be very apreciated! Thanks

======================================================================

EDIT: Ok, I'm not able to find any solution.

At the webconfig, inside assemblies:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

At system.webServer:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<defaultDocument>
<files><add value="Page.aspx" /></files>
</defaultDocument>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,System.Web.Routing,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   </modules>



</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, after trying EVERYTHING:

Bad deployment, an old **PrecompiledApp.config** was hanging around my deploy location, and making everything not work.

My final settings that worked:

- IIS 7.5, Win2k8r2 x64,
- Integrated mode application pool
- *Nothing changes in the web.config* - this means no special handlers for routing. Here's my snapshot of the sections a lot of other posts reference. I'm using FluorineFX, so I do have that handler added, but I did not need any others:

  ```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="None"/>

    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="FluorineGateway" type="FluorineFx.FluorineGateway, FluorineFx"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <!-- Modules for IIS 7.0 Integrated mode -->
      <modules>
        <add name="FluorineGateway" type="FluorineFx.FluorineGateway, FluorineFx" />
      </modules>

      <!-- Disable detection of IIS 6.0 / Classic mode ASP.NET configuration -->
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  ```
- Global.ashx: (only method of any note)

  ```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // Register routes...
      System.Web.Routing.Route echoRoute = new System.Web.Routing.Route(
            "{*message}",
          //the default value for the message
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "message", "" } },
          //any regular expression restrictions (i.e. @"[^\d].{4,}" means "does not start with number, at least 4 chars
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "message", @"[^\d].{4,}" } },
            new TestRoute.Handlers.PassthroughRouteHandler()
         );

      System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(echoRoute);
  }
  ```
- PassthroughRouteHandler.cs - this achieved an automatic conversion from http://andrew.arace.info/stackoverflow to http://andrew.arace.info/#stackoverflow which would then be handled by the default.aspx:

  ```
  public class PassthroughRouteHandler : IRouteHandler {

      public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
          HttpContext.Current.Items["IncomingMessage"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["message"];
          requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("#" + HttpContext.Current.Items["IncomingMessage"], true);
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Comment: ¡Thanks IrishChieftain!, but unfortunately that's exactly the link that I've posted and checked before. I've tried to solve the problem before posting.

Comment: Can you be specific about type of this project - Web Form application project? Are the MVC pages in a separate project or are you trying to mix them (not recommended)?

Comment: Give RouteMagic a shot? http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx

Comment: Thanks again, I can't modify the application as long as I'm only hosting it. Don't know why but IIS is not able to manage the request when there is no ASPX page present. I'll make a try with classic mode.